# How MDM and Remote Access Control apps obtain OEM platform key?

Tags: system-apps, remote-control, teamviewer, airdroid

How MDM and Remote Access Control apps obtain OEM platform key?

What's necessary do to obtain a OEM platform key? How these famous MDM and Remote Access Control do?

- TeamViewer
- AnyDesk
- AirDroid (Business)

In view that all they are using permissions and values like:

- `INJECT_EVENTS`
- `CAPTURE_SECURE_VIDEO_OUTPUT`
- `PRIVATE_FLAG_IS_ROUNDED_CORNERS_OVERLAY`

that requires a OEM platform key to work correctly.